# Geometric meaning of cross product of a design matrix and model coefficients

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model, modeling, matrix

I am trying to understand more about the geometry of linear modeling. Take for example an experiment with one categorical predictor having two levels and a numerical response. If two data points are collected for each predictor level, then the linear equation for the experiment would be:

[image]

Where blue is the design matrix, red is the fitted coefficients, yellow is the fitted responses, and green is the experimental responses.

My understanding is that:

- the green experiment responses can be thought of as a vector in a 4D "model" space
- each column in the blue design matrix can also be thought of a vector in the 4D model space
- but there are only two column vectors in the design matrix, so these two vectors sweep out a 2D "design" space within the 4D model space
- the model fitting procedure projects the green 4D response vector onto the 2D design space

These conclusions are centered around the ideas of "column-space", with the geometry being discussed in terms of 4 dimensions, i.e. the number of elements in the green response vector.

My question is...

What is the geometric meaning of going in the opposite direction?

Specifically, what is the meaning of the cross product of the design matrix and the coefficients matrix (is this even a cross product)?

Also, what is the meaning of multiplying a single row of the design matrix by the coefficients matrix (is this a dot product)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying the design matrix (blue) by fitted coefficients (red) has the geometric interpretation of fitting a line (or higher-dimensional version of a line). A line is just anything that can be represented like $\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \cdots + \beta_p x_p$.

Regarding some of the dimensionality statements:

- The green response vector, is a set points in **one dimension**. This is the case for all common variants of linear models
- Each column of the design matrix corresponds the $x$ value for the regression line $\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \cdots + \beta_p x_p$. At minimum, this will be 1-dimensional ($\beta_0$ only). The actual dimension is $p+1$ (side note - if you have quadratic or interaction terms, I think (?) the dimension is less than $p+1$). In your example, the line is in **two dimensional space**.
- Each row of the design matrix is a data point in the $p+1$ dimensional space.
- If you are familiar with matrix multiplication, multiplying the design matrix by a column vector, will give you the value of the regression line at the set of $X$ points you are evaluating the line at.

Some R code to visualise:

- the black is the data points
- the red points are fitted values, which is the equation $\beta_0 + \beta_1x_i$ evaluated at each data point $i$
- the red line is the linear regression you've just fitted

```
library(ggplot2)
y <- c(1,3,5,7)
pred <- c(0,0,1,1)
mdl <- lm(y ~ pred)
X <- model.matrix(mdl)
Beta <- coef(mdl)

ggplot() +
  geom_point( # actual data
    aes(x = pred, y = y)
    , colour = "black"
  ) +
  geom_point( # fitted
    aes(x = pred, y = X %*% Beta)
    , colour = "red"
  ) +
  geom_line(
    data = data.frame(
      x = seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)
      , y = Beta[1] + Beta[2] * seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)
      )
    , aes(x = x, y = y)
    , colour = "red") +
  labs(x = "Predictor", y = "y")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your detailed response, I understand now that the design matrix columns along with the coefficients, specify a linear equation that is within a dimension equal to the number of columns in the design matrix. Thus, the fitted response on each row is the unique solution for that combination of design matrix information (the x's)? My only confusion still is whether the entire vector of N fitted responses should be thought of as a single point on the regression line, or as a vector pointing in N-space?

Comment: The vector of fitted responses I think would best be thought of as points on a line.

Comment: Great, thanks again!